# How to split comma which ignores if the value is enclose to double quotes

Tags: vbscript

How to split comma which ignores if the value is enclose to double quotes.

Data available:

> 3545,Albert,"Mathias Albert, Lars-Erik Cederman and Alexander Wendt
>   (eds)",2010

Should be splitted in an array:

```
arr(0) = "3545"
arr(1) = "Mathias Albert, Lars-Erik Cederman and Alexander Wendt (eds)"
arr(2) = "2010"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using the ADO Text Driver would probably be the best way in the long run, you can use a specific/custom RegExp for a quick & dirty 'use just once' script:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "^([^,]+),([^,]+),""([^""]+)"",(.+)$"
>> s = "3545,Albert,""Mathias Albert, Lars-Erik Cederman and Alexander Wendt (eds)"",2010"
>> Set m = r.Execute(s)
>> ReDim a(3)
>> For i = 0 To UBound(a)
>>     a(i) = m(0).SubMatches(i)
>> Next
>> WScript.Echo Join(a, vbCrLf)
>>
3545
Albert
Mathias Albert, Lars-Erik Cederman and Alexander Wendt (eds)
2010
>>
```

To cope with empty fields, the .Pattern needs some further fiddling.

If you prefer `Split()`, something like this:

```
>> s = "3545,Albert,""Mathias Albert, Lars-Erik Cederman and Alexander Wendt (eds)"",2010"
>> ReDim a(3)
>> q = Split(s, """")
>> WScript.Echo Join(q, vbCrLf)
>>
3545,Albert,
Mathias Albert, Lars-Erik Cederman and Alexander Wendt (eds)
,2010
>> c = Split(q(0), ",")
>> WScript.Echo Join(c, vbCrLf)
>>
3545
Albert

>> a(0) = c(0)
>> a(1) = c(1)
>> a(2) = q(1)
>> a(3) = Mid(q(2), 2)
>> WScript.Echo Join(a, vbCrLf)
>>
3545
Albert
Mathias Albert, Lars-Erik Cederman and Alexander Wendt (eds)
2010
>>
```

should get you started.